# stem.connection.IncorrectSocketType: unable to use the control socket

Tags: python, stem

Trying to send requests over Tor with `requests[socks]` and renew the IP after `x` amount of requests.

This is the code:

```py
def tor():
    session = requests.session()
    session.proxies = {'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
                       'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'}
    return session

session = tor()

def renew_tor_ip():
    with Controller.from_port(port = 9050) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(password="mypassword")
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

def get_dorks(pages):
    for i in range(pages):
        i += 1
        if i == 0:
            s = session.get("url")
        if i != 0:
            s = session.get("url" + str(i))
            if i == 20:
                renew_tor_ip()
```

when running this I get

```
stem.connection.IncorrectSocketType: unable to use the control socket
```

edit: i changed my torrc file following the "a little relay" article from stem

edit2: have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

9050 is not the port for the controller.
9051 is the port you are looking for.

Alter `with Controller.from_port(port = 9050) as controller`
to    `with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller`

You also have to enable the port in the config file of tor.